# Discrete Frequency representation for central frequency/ discretize up-converted signal in time and frequency

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-communications, sampling, dft, analog-to-digital

I want to analyze a signal after up-conversion in discrete time and frequency, for example:

Let's assume a continuous up-converted signal is:

$$e^{j2\pi ft} \cdot e^{j2\pi f_c t} = e^{j 2 \pi (f+fc) t}$$

What is the discrete-time/frequency version of the above signal? Is it

$$e^{j 2 \pi (k+kc) n /N }$$ ????

Have you ever heard about the discrete central frequency such as kc as mentioned above? In this case, does it should be an integer number?

Do you know any reference has this kind of thing?

Comment: The tricky part here is the sample rate. Typically the baseband signal is sampled at a rate to accommodate it's bandwidth. However the upconverted signal will have a much higher bandwidth and hence you can't upconvert without aliasing. If you upsample the baseband signal first to a sample rate that can accommodate the modulated signal aliasing free your equation is essentially correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost correct, however, not completely. The complex exponential can be written in terms of the analog frequencies as

\begin{equation}e^{j2\pi n\frac{f_{c}+f}{f_{s}}}\end{equation}

The way to convert back to a discrete frequency representation would be something like

\begin{equation}e^{j2\pi n (k_{c}+k)}\end{equation}

Here, it is assumed that $k_{c} +k< 0.5$ to satisfy Nyquist, otherwise the argument of the exponential would jump more than $\pi$ from each index of n to the next, which is aliasing.

You also include a $\frac{1}{N}$ in your complex exponential. This is part of the complex exponentials argument in the Fourier transform to ensure *orthonormality*. The division by $N$ in the Fourier transform ensures the frequency representation is normalized, however, this is not necessary in general.